# Roo gem .xlsx files performance problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am getting unacceptable performace problems by using the roo gem for
reading a file by using XLSX or XLS library from this gem.

Someone may suggest me an alternative about how to parse an .XLSX file?

```
parsed_file = Excel.new(filename,false, :ignore) if (file_format.upcase
== "XLS")
      parsed_file = Excelx.new(filename,false, :ignore) if
(file_format.upcase == "XLSX")
      raise t "#{filename} is not an Excel file!" if (!parsed_file)

      parsed_file.default_sheet =
parsed_file.sheets[0]#'Sheet2'#oo.sheets[1]

      first_row = parsed_file.first_row
      last_row = parsed_file.last_row
      first_column = parsed_file.first_column
      last_column = parsed_file.last_column
      #logger.info "#### Total Rows:#{last_row}, first_row:#{first_row},
last_row:#{last_row}, first_column:#{first_column},
last_column:#{last_column}"

      first_row.upto(last_row) do |current_line|
              # Stuff ....
      end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By the way,

The mongrel servers hangs for .xls or .xlsx from files of 3767 rows such as:

002N6V3 1506 RH-128 YE YEMEN MOBILE BLACK       0,5 KILOGRAMS   Y   Y

002N6V3 1506 RH-128 YE YEMEN MOBILE BLACK       0,5 KILOGRAMS   Y   Y

........

But it worked well for 1000 rows and less.

By the console it worked. but after around 34 mins. Unacceptable in webs. 
By using Spreadsheet takes acceptable time and not hangs mongrels server. Supposedly is more moder roo gem than Spreadsheet.

I used it also as the next way:

```
 parsed_file = Excelx.new(filename,false, :ignore) if (file_format.upcase == "XLSX")
  (1..parsed_file.last_row).each { |row| 
      ret << parsed_file.row(row)          
  }
```

Someone is experiencing the same problems with this gem? Any alternatives apart from running this task in background later by using delayed_jobs?